# Disappearing Sound Output causing audio problems?

Tags: sound

Often when listening to music, or doing anything audio related in Ubuntu, I'll get choppy, irritating volume spikes (which last as long as the blink of an eye).

I looked at my sound settings, and I noticed that this happens whenever a particular output device appears for much less than a second (at the bottom of the list in the screenshot below), and then disappears. It happens quick enough that I can't even get a screenshot of it, it's that fast. Unfortunately I don't have the reputation to post images, so have a Dropbox link.

https://db.tt/guTnubLZ

At the moment I'm using my guitar interface for audio. This is what appears as 'PCM2902 Audio Codec'. The reason I started using this device a while ago was because using the default Analogue Output would have this issue, but now this audio problem seems to be universal. This is really irritating, because it seems like Ubuntu is trying to switch to this other audio output when it shouldn't.